# URI Online Judge 1021

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm having trouble with this challenge, it keeps giving me 100% wrong. Here's my code:

```
N = float(input())

if 0 < N < 1000000:
    print('NOTAS:')
    for i in [100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2]:
        print('%d nota(s) de R$ %d.00' %((N//i),i))
        N %= i

    print('MOEDAS:')
    for i in [1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]:
        print('%d moeda(s) de R$ %.3f' %((N//i),i))
        N %= i
```

Here's what is asked:

> Read a value of floating point with two decimal places. This represents a monetary value. After this, calculate the smallest possible number of notes and coins on which the value can be decomposed. The considered notes are of 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2. The possible coins are of 1, 0.50, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05 and 0.01. Print the message “NOTAS:” followed by the list of notes and the message “MOEDAS:” followed by the list of coins.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input file contains a value of floating point N (0 ≤ N ≤ 1000000.00).
>
> **Output**
>
> Print the minimum quantity of banknotes and coins necessary to change the initial value, as the given example

So, most of the tests I've done gave me the right answers, but when I test 0.06, for example, it doesn't work. Here's the result for the input 0.06:

> 0.06
>
> NOTAS:
>
> 0 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
>
> 0 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
>
> 0 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
>
> 0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
>
> 0 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
>
> 0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
>
> MOEDAS:
>
> 0 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
>
> 0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
>
> 0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
>
> 0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
>
> 1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
>
> 0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01

The result should be "1 moeda de R$ 0.05" and "1 moeda de R$ 0.01". Any thoughts on why this is happening?

> OBS: I think the problem is at the last line, in the 'N %= i' command, which means N = N % i

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8

```
#The problem's with number 43.55
moedas = [1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 0.01]
print('MOEDAS')
for i in moedas:
    result = int(round(N,2)/i
    print(f'{result} moeda(s) de R$ {i:.2f}')
    N -= result * i


NOTAS:
0 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
2 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
```